What is the PciRoot line in my efibootmgr output?
I want to ask two related questions.

If anyone can explain what this means, from left to right. It is an entry in the output of efibootmgr -v: 

Boot0001* UEFI: USB, Partition 2  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(22,0)/HD(2,GPT,e7e777e5-ba64-4290-a759-837b96feb4ed,0x7023fc,0x2130)..BO


Am I correct thinking that this path points to partition 2 of my drive?  If so, why did UEFI firmware pick this up and set an NVRAM variable for it? (It seems to be a path down the PCI Root complex tree that terminates at my sda2 ... ?)

Here are some details:
-- Mobo is ASUS Prime Z590-P. 
-- Disk: There is only one disk, it is not a PCI or an M.2; it is this: 
SATA SSD Samsung 870 EVO 500GB 2.5 Inch SATA III Internal SSD (MZ-77E500B/AM) 

There is nothing else plugged into the system, except a USB Hub (I unplugged it but no change in efibootmgr). 
Connected by Ethernet to XyZEL C3000Z modem-router, DSL.
-- Partitions: Just four: 
sda1 ESP; 
sda2 Kubuntu 22.04 root (/)
sda3 /home
sda4 swap
Output of efibootmgr -v:
BootCurrent: 0000 
Timeout: 1 seconds 
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0004 
Boot0000* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,cfc63277-3e31-4939-bde9-db4429f4fa77,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) 
Boot0001* UEFI: USB, Partition 2  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(22,0)/HD(2,GPT,e7e777e5-ba64-4290-a759-837b96feb4ed,0x7023fc,0x2130)..BO
Boot0002* UEFI:CD/DVD Drive     BBS(129,,0x0) 
Boot0003* UEFI:Removable Device BBS(130,,0x0) 
Boot0004* UEFI:Network Device   BBS(131,,0x0)

In the PCI Root line (Boot 0001*), notice the UUID/GUID: e7e777e5-ba64-4290-a759-837b96feb4ed
That does not correspond to any of the GUIDs that I can see on my drive.
I used the following to check this:
ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid/;  ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/;  blkid;  gdisk /dev/sda
I am not aware of a utility that could do a 'reverse lookup' on that puzzling UUID/GUID.
Actually, I'm not sure I would understand the output of such a look-up.
Any ideas?  Thanks.

Focus on these two lines:
Boot0000* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,cfc63277-3e31-4939-bde9-db4429f4fa77,0x800,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) 
Boot0001* UEFI: USB, Partition 2  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(22,0)/HD(2,GPT,e7e777e5-ba64-4290-a759-837b96feb4ed,0x7023fc,0x2130)..BO

The first one is the first partition on your hard drive and is probably your installed OS.
The second one is the second partition on a usb disk plugged into your system somewhere, so it's no surprise this doesn't match the UUID of your expected disk.
You can find a list of disk uuids with ls -l /dev/disk/by-*uuid/ or alternately lsblk -fe7  and your "mystery" uuid should be in both of these places.
You may find it it as /dev/disk/by-partuuid/e7e777e5-ba64-4290-a759-837b96feb4ed  which should be a symlink to the short device name (probably /dev/sdb2 ).  However this may be less helpful than the device path already listed in your question which clearly shows it is a usb device.

Thanks.  But that first one, Boot 0000*, is the ESP (at sda1). That's OK, no problems. I do see USB in that 2nd one, Boot0001*, but I only have the one drive in my system, and it's a SATA SSD, with the 4 partitions I listed.  As I also mentioned, I used several commands to locate that 'strange' UUID/GUID, but nothing showed up: nothing showed e7e777e5-ba64-4290-a759-837b96feb4ed . I did, also, try the commands you listed.

Yes, sda1 is your ESP, but the OS should be on one of the other three partitions on the same disk, which is your SATA disk.    The USB entry is another ESP on another disk.  It might be interesting to add the lsblk output to your question.  Also note it is possible to have EFI boot entries for devices that are no longer attached to the system.

"The USB entry is another ESP on another disk." Yes, please see the answer.  "...it is possible to have EFI boot entries for devices that are no longer attached to the system."  Yes, and that's concerning, as if it's a firmware glitch.  Thanks.

It's not a glitch, it's intentional.  What if you wanted to put the usb back in and boot it again?  It's also mostly harmless.  If the device doesn't show up in lsblk, you can safely ignore it.  Or delete it.

I agree, thinking about it. Might need the USB to conduct rescue on the OS. Thanks.

With someone's suggestion (Not AI!), I think I found it.  It is an artifact that wasn't cleared out of my system, somehow. It is a partition sdb3, on the USB thumb drive I used (a long time ago) to install Kubuntu 22.04 to my SATA SSD. Amazing! An admin at Kubuntu forums suggested this. This artifact was never cleared out, even after many re-boots of the PC. Could be an ASUS firmware issue. Thank you.
